# Securing textbox input using URL Encoding C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

My current employer stores product descriptions for use in our online catalog in HTML format in the database. For example, this type of thing is commonly stored:

```
<strong>Book 1</strong><br /><em>This book will help you know the things.</em>
```

And while it smells bad and I don't like it, handling it otherwise is not an option in the foreseeable future.

The product descriptions don't always contain mark-up, so I created a tool that allows the business people to update product descriptions inside of a staff-only interface. But "staff-only" includes salespeople and business people who don't have any technical understanding. I currently take the input from a textbox, and then it gets stored in the database for display on the website. Something like the following is parameterized and stored.

```
string productDescription = tbxDescription.Text;
```

And then displayed on the MVC page...

```
@Html.Raw(Model.ProductDescription)
```

Unfortunately (or fortunately), when those users save angle brackets and other markup in that textbox, things blow up on them, because the text isn't URL encoded. I was considering the option of simply encoding the textbox input, but I am concerned about security risks of people being able to save blobs of JavaScript other code that will just be dumped out onto a page.

```
string productDescription = WebUtility.UrlEncode(tbxDescription.Text);
```

So my question has two parts:

1. From a technical perspective, am I right to be concerned about scripts being entered in here?
2. If so, is there a generally accepted way to handle this that allows basic HTML formatting mark-up without potentially plopping nefarious code into the page?

And one more piece of background info: I am not terribly concerned about our business people maliciously inserting bad things to our database or sticking it on a webpage. I am more concerned about those users being the victims of other types of attacks. I'm not a security expert by any means, so just trying to understand the risks as best I can.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) A generally accepted way it to use a so called *html sanitizer* mechanics to clean up HTML and only allow tags which are on a white list. If possible, use it already before stored to the Database, else at least before displaying. Maybe this one would help. https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Answer (score 0):

That's not enough. There are many ways to inject Javascript in it.

I personally use The [HTMLSanitizer library](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer). 
It checks the HTML content against a white-list of elements and attributes. This list could also be easily extended but you'll have to know what exactly you're doing in that case.

Usage is really easy. After installing it using Nuget

You can just simply:

```
var sanitizedHtml = new HtmlSanitizer().Sanitize(<Unsatnizied_HTML_Content>);
```

Also it has been mentioned in OWASP you can find it in this link: 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library